# Return each product with the earliest instance of its latest change

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to find the earliest `created_at` date of the latest `category` for all `products`. I've attached a sample table below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `price` int NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `products` VALUES
  (1, 'Apple', '750', 'Fruit', '2022-01-01 09:00:00'),
  (2, 'Banana', '1000', 'Fruit', '2022-01-01 09:00:00'),
  (3, 'Clementine', '1200', 'Fruit', '2022-01-01 09:00:00'),
  (4, 'Apple', '600', 'Vegetable', '2022-01-02 09:00:00'),
  (5, 'Banana', '900', 'Fruit', '2022-01-02 09:00:00'),
  (6, 'Apple', '750', 'Fruit', '2022-01-03 09:00:00'),
  (7, 'Banana', '900', 'Vegetable', '2022-01-03 09:00:00'),
  (8, 'Banana', '1000', 'Vegetable', '2022-01-04 09:00:00'),
  (9, 'Banana', '600', 'Fruit', '2022-01-05 09:00:00'),
  (10, 'Banana', '1000', 'Fruit', '2022-01-06 09:00:00');
```

So for example, because "Banana" was changed from a vegetable to a fruit in row 9, and hasn't had it's category changed since then, that's the date I'd like to get for that product.

In theory, finding each time the category column was altered for "Banana":

| id | product.name | category | "in_category_since" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Banana | Fruit | 2022-01-01 09:00:00 |
| 7 | Banana | Vegetable | 2022-01-03 09:00:00 |
| 9 | Banana | Fruit | 2022-01-05 09:00:00 |

Returning the latest of those instances:

| id | product.name | category | "in_category_since" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | Banana | Fruit | 2022-01-05 09:00:00 |

And then doing this for each product name:

| id | product.name | category | "in_category_since" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | Apple | Fruit | 2022-01-03 09:00:00 |
| 9 | Banana | Fruit | 2022-01-05 09:00:00 |
| 3 | Clementine | Fruit | 2022-01-01 09:00:00 |

As I've highlighted in the results in the image underneath, from this table I'd like to return the following rows:

(I'm using MySQL 8.0, not 5.6 as shown in the screenshot if this makes things easier.)

[image: Example SQL Fiddle]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we will create a cte with the current category and the previous one. Then we will only return the rows where there was a change, or is the first.
Then we get the maximum date grouped by name. This returns the latest change of category.

```
WITH cte as (
SELECT name, created_at as "in_category_since", category,
         LAG(category, 1)
                OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY created_at ASC)
         as previous_category
FROM products AS p
)
select name, MAX(in_category_since) as in_category_since
from cte as c
where c.category <> c.previous_category
OR c.previous_category is null
group by name
```

Comment: I want to return `2022-01-05 09:00:00` as this is the date of the latest `category` change from vegetable to fruit.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my post, hopefully this explains things better.

Comment: Hi Peter, as per the "Banana" example in my recent edit, even if a Product has been in the same category previously, I only want the earliest instance of that most recent change.

Comment: I have edited the answer, this gives me the right answers

Comment: That works! Thank you :)

Comment: Caution:  This method probably does not scale well.

Comment: I can agree with that one.